# What is exactly novel object captioning? And why 8 classes in MS-COCO are excluded in this task?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, nlp, computer-vision

I am working with image captioning but I am having a hard time to understand precisely the term `novel object captioning`. Is this something that we trained a model on sentence-description pairs, and then apply to a dataset with objects that have never appeared in training process? I read this from [Neural Baby Talk](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.09845.pdf). [DCC](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05284.pdf) also states that in Introduction:

> Existing state-of-the-art caption models lack the ability to
>   form compositional structures which integrate new objects
>   with known concepts without explicit examples of imagesentence pairs. To address this limitation, we propose
>   the Deep Compositional Captioner (DCC) which can combine visual groundings of lexical units to generate descriptions about objects which are not present in caption corpora (paired image-sentence data), but are present in object
>   recognition datasets (unpaired image data) and text corpora
>   (unpaired text data).

And they mentioned about 8 classes of MS-COCO are excluded for `novel object captioning` but I do not really understand the meaning of this step.

> To ensure that excluded objects
>   are at least similar to some included ones, we cluster the 80
>   objects annotated in the MSCOCO segmentation challenge
>   using the vectors from the word2vec embedding described
>   in Section 3.4 and exclude one object from each cluster. The
>   following words are chosen: “bottle”, “bus”, “couch”, “microwave”, “pizza”, “racket”, “suitcase”, and “zebra”.

For the second question, I add here but expect deeper explanation:

> To evaluate the ability of our approach to perform out-of-domain image
>   captioning, we replicate an existing experimental design (Hendricks et
>   al., 2016) using MSCOCO. Following this approach, all images with
>   captions that mention one of eight selected objects (or their
>   synonyms) are excluded from the image caption training set. This
>   reduces the size of the caption training set from 82,783 images to
>   70,194 images. However, the complete caption training set is tokenized
>   as a bag of words per image, and made available as image tag training
>   data. As such, the selected objects are unseen in the image caption
>   training data, but not the image tag training data. The excluded
>   objects, selected by Hendricks et. al. (2016) from the 80 main object
>   categories in MSCOCO, are: ‘bottle’, ‘bus’, ‘couch’, ‘microwave’,
>   ‘pizza’, ‘racket’,‘suitcase’ and ‘zebra’.

Then now, how should I understand `out of domain image captioning`? Is it the same to `novel image captioning`?

Could someone experienced in image captioning help me clarify those questions? I would appreciate your help.